# Query to count boolean property values within Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a grails domain like this

```
Point {
  User user
  Date assignedDate = new Date()
  consumed = false
}
```

I want to do a query that return rows with 
user, count(consumed=true), count(consumed=false)

for example with data

```
| USER | DATE | CONSUMED |
___________________________
|   1  | ...  | true     |
|   1  | ...  | true     |
|   1  | ...  | false    |
|   2  | ...  | true     |
|   2  | ...  | false    |
```

the query must return:

```
| USER | CONSUMED | NOT CONSUMED |
_________________________________
|   1  | 2        | 1            |
|   2  | 1        | 1            |
```

I have to do this in a single query because I need pagination. Best if done with gorm
criteria or hibernate HQL.

I have tried playing with projections but without success.

Any idea?
Thank you

### Workaround

As a workaround I have used hibernate formula mapping with formula suggested by Michael J. Lee.

I have added two mapped fields to

```
    Point {
          User user
          Date assignedDate = new Date()
          consumed = false
          free formula: "CASE WHEN consumed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"
          notFree formula: "CASE WHEN consumed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"
        }
```

And user a criteria query like:

```
    Point.withCriteria{ 
      projections {
          groupProperty('user')
          sum('free')
          sum('notFree')
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your data structured and the query that you want to return doesn't lend nicely to things like criteria queries and dynamic finders.  I would suggest these two options depending on your level of experience and how much data you need to summarize.

**1.) Create a stored procedure or use a named query (better with lots of data)...**

```
SELECT
   user_id as 'USER',
   SUM(CASE WHEN consumed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CONSUMED'
   SUM(CASE WHEN consumed = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as 'NOT CONSUMED'
FROM 
   point
GROUP BY
    user_id
```

**2.) Use groovy's collection closures to do the heavy lifting in grails (use with caution if you have lots of data)**

```
def someControllerMethod() {
    def points = Point.list().groupBy{ it.user } //<-- or use a findAllBy or criteria
    def data = [];
    points.each{ point,values ->
        data << ['USER':point.user, 'CONSUMED':values.count{ it.consumed }, 'UNCONSUMED':values.count{ !it.consumed } ]
    }

   println("this is what it looks like ${data}");
   return data //<-- is a list of maps that should be easy to render in your gsp
}
```

**Please note that I just did the coding off the top of my head and didn't verify the syntax**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Hope there is better way to do it in grails without using a stored procedure...

Comment: If you want to summarize data or do reporting with any ORM it's usually* a better idea to let the database do the work.  I did provided two solutions because if your only dealing with a small amount of data there is no reason to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Add a named query on that domain and use GROUP BY to group your users. You can use COUNT in your select clause

Comment: Please provide some code. How do count the different values of **one** property?

Comment: `with a as (select user_name, COUNT(*) as consumed from usertlb where consumed = 'true' group by user_name),
b as (select user_name, COUNT(*) as not_consumed  from usertlb where consumed = 'false' group by user_name)
select a.user_name, a.consumed, b.not_consumed from a, b where a.user_name = b.user_name;`

This I tried in SQL, but should work with HQL as well